# Why does @array ~~ LIST return false even though @array contains the same elements as LIST?

Tags: perl, smartmatch

I have

```
@a = (1,2,3); print (@a ~~ (1,2,3))
```

and

```
@a = (1,2,3); print (@a == (1,2,3))
```

The first one is the one I expect to work, but it does not print anything. The second one does print 1.

Why? Isn't the smart matching operator `~~` supposed to match in the case of `@a ~~ (1,2,3)`?

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;` : *Useless use of a constant (2) in void context*

Comment: `(1,2,3)` isn't an array, is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: then what is it?

Comment: @Quentin: i am a little confused: why the context is void in `@a~~(1,2,3)`, and how can I force it to be in an array context?

Comment: The second one works by accident. Try `@a=(4,5,6);print (@a==(4,5,6))` instead.

Comment: @mob: by what accident? And what is the logic behind yours `@a=(4,5,6);print (@a==(4,5,6))`? Thank you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit — No, as Jim said in his answer, it is a list.

Comment: In scalar context, an array is evaluated as its size. In scalar context, a list as evaluated as its last element. Your second example is equivalent to `print (3==3)`, but you should be clear where the `3` on each side of the equation comes from. In my `(4,5,6)` example, the expression is equivalent to `print (3==6)`.

Comment: @mob: thank you for the explanation. But why the warning message says `in void context`?

Comment: @Qiang Li - Try `perl -Mdiagnostics -e '@a=(1,2,3);print @a~~(1,2,3)'`

Comment: @Quentin: Indeed. I was making the point in the form of a question.

Comment: @QiangLi: Lists and arrays are distinct. The latter may be initialised from the former.

Comment: @Qiang Li, Perl knows you are discarding the result of the expressions `1` and `2`, so it evaluates them in void context.

Comment: @Qiang Li, There's no such thing as array context. You want (a reference to) an array, which has nothing to do with the context in which some list is evaluated anyway.

Comment: This is a perfectly good question. Smartmatch is just plain confusing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a second, lets consider the slightly different

```
\@a ~~ (1,2,3)
```

`~~` evaluates its arguments in scalar context, so the above is the same as

```
scalar(\@a) ~~ scalar(1,2,3)
```

- `\@a` (in any context) returns a reference to `@a`.
- `1, 2, 3` in scalar context is similar to `do { 1; 2; 3 }`, returning `3`.

So minus a couple of warnings*, the above is equivalent to

```
\@a ~~ 3
```

What you actually want is

```
\@a ~~ do { my @temp = (1,2,3); \@temp }
```

which can be shortened to

```
\@a ~~ [ 1,2,3 ]
```

Finally, the magic of `~~` allows `\@a` to be written as `@a`, so that can be shortened further to

```
@a ~~ [ 1,2,3 ]
```

* — Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: I'd remove my answer, but it illustrates a step in my learning process. I aspire to one day reach your level of understanding.

Comment: You can _edit_ your answer to represent additional steps in your learning process :)

Answer (score 9):

Smart match tries to do what I think you're expecting if you use an array or an array reference on the right side -- but not a list.

```
$ perl -E '@a = (1, 2, 3); say (@a ~~ (1, 2, 3))'

$ perl -E '@a = (1, 2, 3); say ((1, 2, 3) ~~ @a)' # also misguided, but different
1
$ perl -E '@a = (1, 2, 3); say (@a ~~ [1, 2, 3])'
1
```

Comment: Your second example is equivalent to `say 3~~@a`. You'll find that `say ((3,2,1)~~@a)` also prints 1, as does `say ((9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)~~@a)`.

Comment: Oh, wow.  Evaluates as the last item in the list, then does a `scalar ~~ array` "smart" match?

Comment: It's always `scalar ~~ scalar`. `@a` is simply a shortcut for `\@a`.

Answer (score 6):

Start with [What is the difference between a list and an array?](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array-) in the perlfaq. It specifically shows you how your choice of values is wrong.

You might also start by writing out why you expected each to work or not work, so that we might correct your expectations. Why did you think you'd get the results that you expected?

As for the smart match bits, there's no rule for `ARRAY ~~ LIST`. The smart match only works with the pairs enumerated in its table in *perlsyn*. It's going to force it to be one of those pairs.

When you run into these problems, try many more cases:

```
#!perl
use v5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a = (1,2,3);
say "\@a is @a";
say "\@a ~~ (1,2,3) is ", try( @a ~~ (1,2,3) );
say "\@a ~~ [1,2,3] is ", try( @a ~~ [1,2,3] );
say "\@a ~~ 3 is ", try( @a ~~ 3 );
say "3 ~~ \@a is ", try( 3 ~~ @a );

say '';

my @b = (4,5,6);
say "\@b is @b";
say "\@b ~~ (4,5,6) is ", try( @b ~~ (4,5,6) );
say "\@b ~~ [4,5,6] is ", try( @b ~~ [4,5,6] );
say "\@b ~~ 3 is ", try( @b ~~ 3 );
say "3 ~~ \@b is ", try( 3 ~~ @b );

say '';
say "\@b ~~ \@a is ", try( @b ~~ @a );

sub try { $_[0] || 0 }
```

The output of the various cases is the clue that you misread the docs:

```
Useless use of a constant (2) in void context at test.pl line 8.
Useless use of a constant (4) in void context at test.pl line 17.
Useless use of a constant (5) in void context at test.pl line 17.
@a is 1 2 3
@a ~~ (1,2,3) is 0
@a ~~ [1,2,3] is 1
@a ~~ 3 is 0
3 ~~ @a is 1

@b is 4 5 6
@b ~~ (4,5,6) is 0
@b ~~ [4,5,6] is 1
@b ~~ 3 is 0
3 ~~ @b is 0

@b ~~ @a is 0
```